# error: value orderBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When running this code:

```scala
df
    .select($"CALC_DATE", $"ENGINE_SERIES", $"program_group_name")
    .groupBy($"CALC_DATE", $"ENGINE_SERIES", $"program_group_name")
    .orderBy($"CALC_DATE".desc)
    .count()
    .withColumnRenamed("count", "Actual_count")
    .show()
```

I get the following error:

```
error: value orderBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the error message, `orderBy` cannot be used on a `RelationalGroupedDataset`.

The `groupBy` function does not return a basic `DataFrame` like the `where`, `select` or even `orderBy` functions. It returns a `RelationalGroupedDataset` on which you can only apply aggreation functions, such as `count` in your example. The aggregation function will then return a `DataFrame` that you will be able to sort.

In your case, just switch `orderBy` and `count` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Basically GroupBy will return the RelationalGroupedDataset which means a Relation to a Dataset which contain some groups.
Now To convert this RelationalGroupedDataset to a Dataframe you need to specify at least one aggregation for each of the group for this dataset.
Now this aggregation could be anything like count, sum or you can also apply multiple aggregation using .agg() method on RelationalGroupedDataset.
Once you convert this RelationalGroupedDataset to normal Dataframe than you can use normal orderBy and other functions on this Dataframe.